# Unable to use FREEFORM in XCODE STORYBOARD

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

**XCODE VERSION = 5.1**

I am trying to use freeform in storyboard. I have done as below

[image]

[image]

As I increase height, say 1000, it shows strange on storyboard as below

[image]

What is problem here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u use the `freeform` set `height` and `width` what ever your needs

[image]

check this also u followed or not

[image]